# CORS: Preflight Missing Allow Origin Header

Tags: php, rest, nginx

I am using nginx with PHP and Vue. I`m struggling with CORS error like in a title. I can make normal Fetch requests, however when i want to make some application error from backend (for example, when someone want to create a account, and login is already taken). Im getting Error like in title:

Fetch failed and latern in Network Tab in Dev Tools:
`CORS: Preflight Missing Allow Origin Header`

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    root /app/;
    index index.php;

    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" *;
    
    location / {


        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Way i try to send error:

```
        header("HTTP/1.0 460 Aplication Error");
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        json_encode($error);
```

Am i trying to do in proper way at all?

PS Update, i cant change this header, when using calling it by fetch from  Vue CLI Server, when i call it directly for example in browser it works correctly

Comment: "Im getting Error" - what error? I assume it is a CORS error, but we need to know what is specifically says

Comment: Same as in title :) Edited and added inside text.

Comment: A Preflight request is made using the OPTIONS method, your system needs to be set up to properly handle that. And you must answer with 200 OK to this request, you can not respond with an error status code. (You need to do that on the following, _actual_ GET/POST request.)